# oozie spark action table not found

Tags: apache-spark, hive, oozie, oozie-workflow

I am trying to set up a spark action workflow within apache oozie though I'm getting the following error when `select * from db.table` is called within my spark code in a hive context:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table not found: `db`.`table`; line 1 pos 34
```

This spark job works with spark-submit so I can't seem to nail down the issue. I've added hive-site.xml to various locations recommended in previous questions such as the workspace lib directory and the workspace directory and added it to the job.xml setting though I still get the same issue.

I'm running in deploy mode cluster and master yarn.

I've tried many combinations and not sure what else to do.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you share your workflow code? It's usually issue with `credentials` node.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to add the Hive configuration. For example, adding in the action of the workflow de file where it is.

```
<spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:1.0">
   <!-- ... ->
   <file>${hiveConfig}</file>
</spark>
```

In job.properties must be the reference:

```
hiveConfig=/user/oozie/extraconfig/hive-site.xml
```

This file must be in each node of cluster